# How do I use NSConditionLock? Or NSCondition

Tags: iphone, ios, locking, conditional-statements

I am try to make one function wait for another, and I would like to use NSCondionLock in order to accomplish this. I am not asking for help, but really hoping someone could show me a decent tutorial or example to explain NSConditionLock, or possibly suggest a better method.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**EDIT:** as @Bonshington commented, this answer refers to `NSCondition` (as opposed to `NSConditionLock`):

```
- (void) method1 {

    [myCondition lock];
    while (!someCheckIsTrue)
        [myCondition wait];


    // Do something.


    [myCondition unlock];
}

- (void) method2 {

    [myCondition lock];


    // Do something.


    someCheckIsTrue = YES;
    [myCondition signal];
    [myCondition unlock];
}
```

The `someCheckIsTrue` can be anything, it could be a simple BOOL variable or even something like `[myArray count] == 0 && color == kColorRed`, it doesn't matter. It only matters that in one method you check for a condition *while you have the lock* and in another method you make changes that can make the condition become true *also while having the lock*. The magic is the `wait` and `signal` part: the `wait` actually unlocks the lock and reacquires it after some other thread called `signal`.

Comment: How do I declare it? Is it just NSConditionLock *lock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] init] ? And should I declare it in whatever method calls the two function that need to be synchronized? Sorry if I did not format my comment properly, this is my first time really posting.

Comment: You should declare it as an instance variable in your class, `NSConditionLock *lock;`. You then initialize it in your `init` with `lock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] init];`, that's it. Also, in `dealloc`, you simply release it: `[lock release];`. Or if the methods are in different classes, then you need to define the lock somewhere where both methods have access to.

Comment: So in this case, is the method 1 waiting for the second method? Or vice versa? Because when I implemented this, my program gets stuck on [MyConditionLock wait]

Comment: @gurooj: First of all, the methods must run on different threads. So they may not call each other, otherwise you'd have a deadlock. Now, first `method1` needs to run and hit `wait`, then `method2` will wake it up with `signal`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help. I ended up using performSelectorOnMainThread and performSelectorInBackground to accomplish the task anyways. The waitUntilDone parameter allowed me to skip all the condition code.

Comment: NSConditionLock doesn't have wait, signal. its NSCondition

Comment: Shouldn't someCheckIsTrue be set to YES before the sensitive code is executed?

Comment: As long as the variable is only every read or set between `[myCondition lock];` and `[myCondition unlock];` it doesn't matter when exactly you set the variable. As long as you only access it between `lock` and `unlock` you can consider these blocks to be atomic. That's the whole point of mutexes and locks.

Comment: but what if multiple threads are stuck on "while (!someCheckIsTrue)" and then the signal happens? Can they 2 threads at the same time pass that condition before the bool is set to false again?

Comment: @MobileMon: No. Quote from the [documentation of `signal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCondition/signal): _You use this method to wake up **one** thread that is waiting on the condition._ (emphasize mine)

Answer (score 33):

For those that want a sample test class here I post what I did to play around and understand how NSCondition works.

```
// --- MyTestClass.h File --- //
@interface MyTestClass

- (void)startTest;

@end

// --- MyTestClass.m File --- //
@implementation MyTestClass
{
    NSCondition *_myCondition;
    BOOL _someCheckIsTrue;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
        _someCheckIsTrue = NO;
        _myCondition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Public Methods

- (void)startTest
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(_method1) withObject:nil];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        sleep(5);
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(_method2) withObject:nil];
    });
}

#pragma mark Private Methods

- (void)_method1
{
    NSLog(@"STARTING METHOD 1");

    NSLog(@"WILL LOCK METHOD 1");
    [_myCondition lock];
    NSLog(@"DID LOCK METHOD 1");

    while (!_someCheckIsTrue)
    {
        NSLog(@"WILL WAIT METHOD 1");
        [_myCondition wait];
        NSLog(@"DID WAIT METHOD 1");
    }

    NSLog(@"WILL UNLOCK METHOD 1");
    [_myCondition unlock];
    NSLog(@"DID UNLOCK METHOD 1");

    NSLog(@"ENDING METHOD 1");
}

- (void)_method2
{
    NSLog(@"STARTING METHOD 2");

    NSLog(@"WILL LOCK METHOD 2");
    [_myCondition lock];
    NSLog(@"DID LOCK METHOD 2");

    _someCheckIsTrue = YES;

    NSLog(@"WILL SIGNAL METHOD 2");
    [_myCondition signal];
    NSLog(@"DID SIGNAL METHOD 2");

    NSLog(@"WILL UNLOCK METHOD 2");
    [_myCondition unlock];
    NSLog(@"DID UNLOCK METHOD 2");
}

@end


// --- Output --- //
/*
2012-11-14 11:01:21.416 MyApp[8375:3907] STARTING METHOD 1
2012-11-14 11:01:21.418 MyApp[8375:3907] WILL LOCK METHOD 1
2012-11-14 11:01:21.419 MyApp[8375:3907] DID LOCK METHOD 1
2012-11-14 11:01:21.421 MyApp[8375:3907] WILL WAIT METHOD 1
2012-11-14 11:01:26.418 MyApp[8375:4807] STARTING METHOD 2
2012-11-14 11:01:26.419 MyApp[8375:4807] WILL LOCK METHOD 2
2012-11-14 11:01:26.419 MyApp[8375:4807] DID LOCK METHOD 2
2012-11-14 11:01:26.420 MyApp[8375:4807] WILL SIGNAL METHOD 2
2012-11-14 11:01:26.420 MyApp[8375:4807] DID SIGNAL METHOD 2
2012-11-14 11:01:26.421 MyApp[8375:4807] WILL UNLOCK METHOD 2
2012-11-14 11:01:26.421 MyApp[8375:3907] DID WAIT METHOD 1
2012-11-14 11:01:26.421 MyApp[8375:4807] DID UNLOCK METHOD 2
2012-11-14 11:01:26.422 MyApp[8375:3907] WILL UNLOCK METHOD 1
2012-11-14 11:01:26.423 MyApp[8375:3907] DID UNLOCK METHOD 1
2012-11-14 11:01:26.423 MyApp[8375:3907] ENDING METHOD 1
*/
```

Comment: Thank you but your example doesn't illustrate why using `while (!_someCheckIsTrue)` instead of `if (!_someCheckIsTrue)`.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5** version of @vilanovi answer from Playground:

```swift
let myCondition = NSCondition()

var someCheckIsTrue = false

func method1() {
    print("STARTING METHOD 1")

    print("WILL LOCK METHOD 1")
    myCondition.lock()
    print("DID LOCK METHOD 1")

    while (!someCheckIsTrue) {
        print("WILL WAIT METHOD 1")
        myCondition.wait()
        print("DID WAIT METHOD 1")
    }

    print("WILL UNLOCK METHOD 1")
    myCondition.unlock()
    print("DID UNLOCK METHOD 1")

    print("ENDING METHOD 1")
}

func method2() {
    print("STARTING METHOD 2")

    print("WILL LOCK METHOD 2")
    myCondition.lock()
    print("DID LOCK METHOD 2")

    someCheckIsTrue = true

    print("WILL SIGNAL METHOD 2")
    myCondition.signal()
    print("DID SIGNAL METHOD 2")

    print("WILL UNLOCK METHOD 2")
    myCondition.unlock()
    print("DID UNLOCK METHOD 2")

    print("ENDING METHOD 2")
}

DispatchQueue.global().async {
    method1()
}

DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5) {
    method2()
}
```

Comment: Why is method2() locking and unlocking it? Is it required?

Answer (score 4):

`NSConditionLock` example program.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define IDLE 0
#define START 1
#define TASK_1_FINISHED 2
#define TASK_2_FINISHED 3
#define CLEANUP_FINISHED 4

#define SHARED_DATA_LENGTH 1024 * 1024 * 1024

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSConditionLock *lock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:IDLE];
        char *shared_data = calloc(SHARED_DATA_LENGTH, sizeof(char));

        [NSThread detachNewThreadWithBlock:^{
            [lock lockWhenCondition:START];

            NSLog(@"[Thread-1]: Task 1 started...");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < SHARED_DATA_LENGTH; i++) {
                shared_data[i] = 0x00;
            }
            [lock unlockWithCondition:TASK_1_FINISHED];
        }];

        [NSThread detachNewThreadWithBlock:^{
            [lock lockWhenCondition:TASK_1_FINISHED];
            NSLog(@"[Thread-2]: Task 2 started...");
            for (size_t i = 0; i < SHARED_DATA_LENGTH; i++) {
                char c = shared_data[i];
                shared_data[i] = ~c;
            }
            [lock unlockWithCondition:TASK_2_FINISHED];
        }];

        [NSThread detachNewThreadWithBlock:^{
            [lock lockWhenCondition:TASK_2_FINISHED];

            NSLog(@"[Thread-3]: Cleaning up...");
            free(shared_data);
            [lock unlockWithCondition:CLEANUP_FINISHED];
        }];

        NSLog(@"[Thread-main]: Threads set up. Waiting for 2 task to finish");
        [lock unlockWithCondition:START];
        [lock lockWhenCondition:CLEANUP_FINISHED];
        NSLog(@"[Thread-main]: Completed");
    }
    return 0;
}
```