# ios application crashes when deleting line in uitableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem in my UITableView which filled with `data: [(gamme: String, [(product: String, quantity: Double)])]`, everything works fine: inserting rows and sections, deleting row and section, reloading. 
But sometimes and when I try to delete lots of lines in fast way (line by line by swiping the line the table and tap (-) ). it leads to a crash like in the screenshot.

The issue is hard to reproduce in development app. but my clients still reports it. My clients are professionals (not normal users) and are expected to use the in a fast way with medium to large data.

[image]

and this is my func that delete lines:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "-") { (action, indexPath) in

        let cmd = self.groupedData[indexPath.section].1.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
        self.delegate?.didDeleteCmdLine(cmd)

        if self.groupedData[indexPath.section].1.count == 0 {
            self.groupedData.remove(at: indexPath.section)
            tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section), with: UITableViewRowAnimation.right)
        }
    }

    return [delete]
}
```

why is that happening ?

*This is a screen of xcode organiser for the crash*

[image]
**Edit:**

Checking if `groupedData` is accessed by any thread other than main proposed by @Reinhard:

```
private var xgroupedData = [(gamme: GammePrdCnsPrcpl, [cmdline])]()

private var groupedData: [(gamme: GammePrdCnsPrcpl, [cmdline])] {
    get {
        if !Thread.isMainThread {
            fatalError("getting from not from main")
        }
        return xgroupedData
    }
    set {
        if !Thread.isMainThread {
            fatalError("setting from not from main")
        }
        xgroupedData = newValue
    }
}
```

but the `groupedData` variable is accessed only from main thread

Comment: Why are you deleting an entire section?

Comment: If the section (gamme) has no more products, it has to be deleted too

Comment: @brahimm Is that a real screenshot of the production version of your app? If so, you might want to get rid of the API key in there!

Comment: @dnlggr thanks man, but no that one is just for dev

Comment: I think it could be you are copying index paths in to the row action closure. Try and copy the model object in to the block instead, then recalculate the section index that you're removing inside the closure itself.

Comment: I think what could be happening is:
1) You're copying a reference to an indexpath
2) Deleting said section, thereby offsetting all subsequent sections who previously thought they were one section greater than they now are,
3) Then accessing a copied version of a now invalidated indexpath and trying to do work with it, potentially leading to an out of bounds style exception. ...

You can probably confirm by:
1) Scroll to bottom of table view
2) Delete the second last section,
3) Delete the last section.
4) Crash?

Comment: I tested it as you said but no crash, I tries as hard as I could but couldn't get it to crash, in the way you said, and any other possible way. but still getting crash reports

Comment: I generally use collection view rather than table view. Does `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?` get called at time of swipe, or at time of cell appearance?
If at time of swipe then speed may be a factor as the indexpath isn't copied into the block until when the swipe starts. I think it is still possible for invalid index paths to be copied if the animation of the previous delete action is still ongoing.

Comment: What happens when you: 1) Swipe to reveal the actions drawer (but don't delete). 2) Swipe the preceding cell and delete it. 3) Swipe the cell from step 1 and this time do delete it. 4) Crash?

Comment: Hi, the func is called on swipe, so I swiped an other cell, the indepxPath will changes on each swipe. I tried what you said but nothing happened. as I said it is hard to repreduce it, we still dont know what maneuver generate the crash

Comment: Since your app crashes, it seems that you did not set an exception breakpoint. With an exception breakpoint, your app would stop where the exception occurs, and you should get better information in the log.

Answer (score 6):

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. Somehow this worked !! can you elaborate

Comment: When you reload all tableview , sometimes error is occured because resuseable cells. This may be due to several reasons ( Data count , nil value etc. ). But now you only reload specific cell . If this a true answer for you , please mark as accepted.

Comment: the problem still occures! if I try to delete fastly is crashes the same way. is there any other ideas?

Comment: did you try to freeze tableview scroll when delete action runs ?

Comment: what do you mean? no I did not do anything with the scroll

Comment: The error occures when try to delete fastly ?. Before the deleteRow & deleteData action , freeze tableView Scroll https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410777/how-can-i-programmatically-force-stop-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview

Comment: @AliIhsanURAL and why should this be the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Changes in João Luiz Fernandes answer....try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                if editingStyle == .delete {
                    objects.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                } else if editingStyle == .insert {
                    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
                }
            }
```

reference  (Hacking with swift . https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-swipe-to-delete-uitableviewcells )

Comment: @zgue what is wrong in this solution..?.. plz explain

Comment: I only edited your answer in the review queue. The down vote comes from someone other.

Comment: @RajanSingh I had tried it but the still crashes sometimes

Comment: It is the same as n the screen shot is my question

Answer (score 1):

u can try this

```
         var myDataArray = ["one","two","three"]
         //wanna insert a row then in button action or any action write
         myDataArray.append("four")
         self.tblView.reloadData()
         // wanna delete a row
         myDataArray.removeObject("two")
         // you can remove data at any specific index liek
         //myDataArray.remove(at: 2)
         self.tblView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay, you actually should do `tblView.insertRow(indexPath)` when appending a value to data. because `reloadData()` will refresh all the tableView which is no necessary

Comment: @brahimm then use tblview.reloadrows at indexpath which reload yr recent row then your all data will not reload

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("Deleted")

        // do your delete your entires here..
        //

        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but the problem is still there. and this func dose not give the swipe option until you set the tableview to `isEditing = true`

Comment: Got it, so do you want to delete the rows just by swiping?

Comment: yes. look like the answer down below worked for me. thank you

Comment: Yeah, the another answer probably works fine to you. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

After the user tapped the delete button, you remove the corresponding row and (if this was the last row of that section) the corresponding section from your data source `groupedData`, which is an array. However, **array operations are not thread-safe**.
Can it be that another thread is using this array while it is modified by the delete action?
In this case, the app can crash. The danger is of course higher, when several actions are triggered in a short time, which seems to be the case as you described it.
One way (maybe not the best) to avoid multithreading problems is to access the array only on the main thread.
If this slows down the main thread, one can use a synchronised array that allows multiple reads concurrently, but only a single write that blocks out all reads, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51916230/1987726).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. I tried you proposal (see edited question), but I see that the grroupedData is access only by main thread

Comment: So, if you access your array only from the main thread, my answer does not apply, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is just a update @codeByThey's answer. 
 Please Update your DataSource file as you delete that particular row.

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
self.whatEverDataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

This will result that your DataSource is also update same time as the TableView. The crash is happening may be due to the DataSource is not updated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replay. this was actually the implementation I'm using already .

Comment: I meant that this was the implémentations I was using and the one crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the section at once instead of trying to remove the row once, and then the section which it belongs to, when the last item in a section is being removed?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "-") { [weak self] (action, indexPath) in

        // Use a weak reference to self to avoid any reference cycles.
        guard let weakSelf = self else {
            return
        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()

        let cmd: cmdline
        if weakSelf.groupedData[indexPath.section].1.count > 1 {
            cmd = weakSelf.groupedData[indexPath.section].1.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
        } else {
            // Remove the section when the `items` are empty or when the last item is to be removed.
            cmd = weakSelf.groupedData.remove(at: indexPath.section).1[indexPath.row]
            tableView.deleteSections([indexPath.section], with: .right)
        }
        weakSelf.delegate?.didDeleteCmdLine(cmd)

        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    return [delete]
}
```